# python os.system doesn't work as expect

Tags: python, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to generate a very simple pdf using wkhtmltopdf tool and python:

```
# html string (works fine in all browsers)
html = generate_html()
f = open("/tmp/sudoku.html", 'w')
f.write(html)
system('wkhtmltopdf /tmp/sudoku.html sudoku.pdf')
f.close()
```

The resulting pdf is blank, but if i call wkhtmltopdf directly from the command line, it works:

```
wkhtmltopdf /tmp/sudoku.html sudoku.pdf
```

Why is that?
Thanks.

Comment: Im guessing you imported `import os` shouldnt you be using it `os.system('wkhtmltopdf /tmp/sudoku.html sudoku.pdf')`

Comment: No, i did *from os import system*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `/tmp/sudoku.html` already contains content, you need to close the file object first before calling `wkhtmltopdf` to generate a PDF from it. Unless you `flush` what you have already written to the file, nothing will be output to `/tmp/sudoku.html` until you close the file. Try:

```
html = generate_html()
f = open("/tmp/sudoku.html", 'w+')
f.write(html)
f.close() # close the file first
system('wkhtmltopdf /tmp/sudoku.html sudoku.pdf')
```